# Couldn't figure out where my data was passed in networking Swift

Tags: ios, swift, networking, decode

I'm new to Swift and generally lack of experience in programming. Currently I'm working on a project trying to display a list of star war characters on view controller, but I'm having some issues in passing data through networking Manager. When I ran the program, I couldn't get the name label displayed on the screen.
I have checked the tableView cell and the label is connected with `viewController`. I feel that the problem is somewhere related with networking manager but couldn't figure out by myself.

```
var charactersArray: [Characters] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    getCharacters(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.starWarTableViewController.reloadData()
        }
    }
    self.title = "Star War Characters"
    // print(charactersArray), returns an empty array
}

private func getURL() -> String {
    return "https://swapi.dev/api/people/"
}

func getCharacters(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.starWarTableViewController.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
    self.starWarTableViewController.dataSource = self
    self.starWarTableViewController.delegate = self
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        for i in 1...20 {
            NetworkingManager.shared.getDecodedObject(from: self.getURL() + "\(i)"){
                  (characters: Characters?, error) in
                  guard let characters = characters else{ return }
                  self.charactersArray.append(characters)
                  print(self.charactersArray) //this will return an array list of characters names
            }
        }
        print(self.charactersArray) // here the characterArray is empty
    }
    completion()
}
```

For what I found, the issue seems in my networking manager or the table view cell

```
enum NetworkError: Error {
    case invalidURLString
}

final class NetworkingManager{
    
    static let shared = NetworkingManager()
    
    private init(){
        
    }
    
    func getDecodedObject <T: Decodable> (from urlString: String, completion: @escaping (T?, Error?) -> Void){
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion(nil, NetworkError.invalidURLString)
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){
            (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else{
                completion(nil, error)
                return }
            guard let characters = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) else{ return }
            completion(characters, nil)
        }.resume()
    }   
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    
    func configure (with characters: Characters) {
        self.nameLabel.text = characters.name
    }
}
```

Here is Characters

```
struct Characters: Decodable {
    let name: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
//        print(name), this will return a list of character names
    }
}
```

This is the tableview extension

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.charactersArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.configure(with: self.charactersArray[indexPath.row])
//        cell.nameLabel.text = "Hi"
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You gotta read up on asynchronous programming. In a nutshell, where you call `completion()` right now, the data hasn't been yet retrieved (which will only be retrieved at some later point - i.e. *asynchronously*). Also, because you're fetching the data from multiple URLs, you meed to "wait" until they all have been retrieve (read about [DispatchGroup.notify](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup)), and only then call `completion()`

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, I would rename `Characters` to something that is singular (i.e. without the trailing `s`) as it obviously represents a single named character, not a collection of them. And I'd avoid `Character` as it conflicts with a standard type of the same name. I don't know what sort of “characters” these names represent, so I can't make a concrete suggestion, but just a few thoughts on the naming of model types...

Comment: Below I've answered the question on how to perform 20 queries, gather the results in sorted order, and update the model and UI when it's done. That having been said, the right solution is generally to write and endpoint in your server to return the 20 values in a single response. What we're doing here is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are initiating a series of asynchronous network requests, but calling the completion handler after the requests are initiated, rather than waiting for when them to finish. Thus, when you call `completion`, the results have not been received.

When you start a bunch of asynchronous tasks and you want to know when they are done, a common pattern is to use `DispatchGroup`, calling `enter` before the asynchronous call, calling `leave` in the completion handler, and then specifying what you want to do when they are all done in a closure supplied to `notify`. If you put your call to your own completion handler in `notify`, then it will not get called until the requests are done and you have data to present in the UI.

A few other observations:

1. `getDecodedObject` is already asynchronous method, so there's no need to dispatch it to a background queue.
2. You will want to update both the model and the UI from the main queue. (`URLSession` calls its completion handlers on a serial background queue.) To accomplish this can basically tell the aforementioned `notify` to run its closure on the `.main` queue. I would also not update the model object until you are ready to update the UI.
3. When performing a series of asynchronous network requests in parallel, you have no assurances of the order in which they may complete. So, you would generally want to use some structure that is independent of the order that the tasks finish, such as a dictionary. Then, when they are done, if you want to build a sorted array of results, then build the array of results from that.

Thus:

```
func getCharacters(completion: @escaping ([Characters]) -> Void) {
    // to keep track of when the 20 requests finish

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    // temporary structure to keep track of the results

    var charactersDictionary: [Int: Characters] = [:]

    // perform the requests

    for i in 1...20 {
        group.enter()
        NetworkingManager.shared.getDecodedObject(from: getURL() + "\(i)") { (characters: Characters?, error) in
            defer { group.leave() }
            guard let characters = characters else { return }
            charactersDictionary[i] = characters
        }
    }

    // when the group tells us that all 20 are done, let's build array of the
    // results and pass it back to the main queue via the completion handler parameter.

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        let results = (1...20).compactMap { charactersDictionary[$0] }
        print(results)
        completion(results)
    }
}
```

Note, by the way, I have pulled the table configuration code out of this routine (as you really don't want to intermingle network code with UI code):

```
func configureTableView() {
    starWarTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
    starWarTableView.dataSource = self
    starWarTableView.delegate = self
}
```

I've also renamed that outlet to be `starWarTableView`, because it is not a view controller, but a table view:

Anyway, you would then call it like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureTableView()

    getCharacters { characters in
        self.charactersArray = characters
        self.starWarTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```